# How to highlight rows in datagridview that not equal to rows in datatable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, match, highlight

I have a datagridview contains many rows of numbers. And I have a datatable with one column contains numbers.

I want to highlight datagridview rows that not in datatable rows .. I compare between just one column.

Here is my code:

```
DataTable SeatNum = new DataTable();

SeatNum = "Select Nums from dbo.Nums";

try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow) { return; }

        foreach (DataRow dtrow in SeatNum.Rows)
        {
            if (dtrow[0].ToString() != (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
            {
                row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                MessageBox.Show("Not Exist" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "\r\n" + dtrow[0].ToString(), "Caution", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
                MessageBox.Show("Exist" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "\r\n" + dtrow[0].ToString(), "Caution", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

This code just highlight the rows that not match to the first row in datatable

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The second `foreach` loop looks odd. `foreach (DataRow dtrow in SeatNum.Rows)` … then in the `if` statement, there is a `break` in the `then` AND `else` conditions. Therefore, the loop will only execute once.

Comment: when i remove the break all the rows were highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code and now it's working like i expected.

I replaced :

```
foreach (DataRow dtrow in SeatNum.Rows)
```

To for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SeatNum.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Then i changed the if statement to:

```
if (SeatNum.Rows[i][0].ToString() != (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
```

Then I removed the `break` in `Then` statement and kept it in `else` statement.

Thanks.

UPTATE:

Better solution, Faster and Logical

```
            DataTable SeatNum;
            List<int> SeatNums = (from row in SeatNum.AsEnumerable() select Convert.ToInt32(row["Num"])).ToList();
            bool OutOfRang = false; ;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {

                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    if (!SeatNums.ToList().Contains(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value)))
                    {
                        OutOfRang = true;
                        row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        MessageBox.Show("This Num ( " + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + " ) not in DataTable list");
                        countSeatsbr++;
                        row.ErrorText = "Not in DataTable list.";

                    }
                }
            }
            if (OutOfRang)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                DoSomethingElse()
            }
```